# How to add lines between individual data points?

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to make a scatter plot in Highcharts that only connects two individual points to  each other, but doesn't connect to any other points. (To show the change in a data point over time).

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/2MdEN/) I illustrate my question. I'd like for there to be a line between the points

`[20, 20]` and `[80, 80]`

and a separate line connecting

`[60, 40]` to `[85, 60]`

but no line connecting

`[80, 80]` to `[60, 40]`

Is there an easily configurable way to do this, or do I have to manually render each line?

Comment: jsfiddle link is not working.

Comment: @AliRızaAdıyahşi Fixed the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simple add `null` between these points.

```
data: [[20, 20], [80, 80], null, [60, 40], [85, 60]]
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2MdEN/1/)