# Surround Highcharts points

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm working on a project where we have some `Highcharts` graphs populated from database; one of them is an scatter graph and we need to surround the points placed on the outside area of the graph.

We need a graph like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/polygon/) but we need the area surrounding the outside points of the scatter; is there a easy way to do this with `Highcharts`? 
We need it to work on IE11 (client's specs).

We can do it with a new polygon serie to make by getting it from codebehind or from database, but that may take too much development time and will slow down the queries. So we need to know if there is an easier way to do it via `Highcharts` or `Javascript`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need to be more specific. Perhaps provide an illustration? Are you asking about how to build the series, or are you asking how to calculate the data points required to encompass certain points? Do you mean all of the points? Or do you mean specifically the "outer" points that you mention? Etc...

Comment: I'm asking if `Highcharts` have any tool to surround the outer points; we know how to make the serie and how to calculate the points, but we want to know if there is and easier way provided by the API or any javascript code without getting the new serie from codebehind.

Comment: Highcharts does not have anything built in to accomplish this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not very familiar with Highcharts, but i could not find such functionality in [their API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts). 
 However there is an easy algorithm to solve your problem.
All you need is to have an array containing the border elements and connect the points from this list like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14960490/how-to-add-lines-between-individual-data-points).

Finding those points is not too hard. Compute the linear equation between two extreme points (like the one on the very top and very right). 
 The resulting formula looks like
 `f(x) = m*x + b`

Now you check for all points within that x-range if their y-coordinate is higher than this line (or lower when doing it with the point on the very bottom). If so just add them to your border array and continue with the other extreme points.